# Каталог на вордпресс

Tags: php, wordpress

Подскажите, как создать такой каталог, как по приведённой ссылке?
http://www.hanwha.com.ph/interior-film/product-categories/wood/premium-wood-xp
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
т.е. чтобы слева были категории, справа товары.
Есть ли похожие плагины?
также чтобы можно было добавлять такие товары

Comment: Это тема нужна, а не плагины

Comment: @Микола Мірчук, а разве нельзя woocommerce подогнать под этот шаблон? наверно есть же какой-то плагин, позволяющий реализовать данную функциональность, может с меньшим функционалом, чем в woocommerce

Comment: тема уже есть установленная, нужен именно плагин чтобы расширить функциональность, подскажите пожалуйста, какой может подойти